# Why can't I summon my friend to help me?

Tags: xbox-360, dark-souls-2

I've just started my first Dark Souls 2 experience and a friend of mine has offered to help out with some of the bosses. I'm trying to summon him for the Pursuer boss fight, but for some reason we cannot connect. I know SL aren't a problem, he's using a SL 30 character whilst I'm using a SL 26 character. The only other thing I can think of is that I'm playing the original DS2 for Xbox 360 whereas he's playing Scholar of The First Sin, also for the 360. Would that make a difference?

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot connect"? Do you not find the summon sign? Is there an error when he tries to connect?

Comment: Oh Sorry. His Summon sign just does not appear.

Comment: [Soul memory](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Soul+Memory) is what DS2 uses to match up players for coop, not soul level. Just fyi

Comment: Can you see other signs? It might be hard to tell if there's just no one else playing in your range but if you do see other signs at least we'll know that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm playing the original DS2 for Xbox 360 whereas he's playing Scholar of The First Sin

Yes, that's exactly why you can't coop (or invade).

Original DS 2 and Scholar are considered two different games, even with the DLC patch for original DS 2.

I guess the non compatibility issue comes from the fact that enemy placement are different between the two games.

Edit : seems like my answer is right for the PC version but I've stumble on different answer for the consoles version. Will continue to dig.

Comment: So my answer was wrong. On old gens (Ps3 / X360) you should be able to connect to one another if the games are on the same release/update.

Answer (score 0):

Are either of you a member of the [Company of Champions](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Company+of+Champions)? Summoning is not allowed in this Covenant, and the game is made much more difficult for next to no reward. It's easy to fall prey to this Covenant, as it is one of the first things you can come across in Majula. There are no messages or hints that tell you the nature of this Covenant either, so if you enter it unwittingly, you won't be able to summon your friends, and the game basically becomes NG+.

Additionally, Soul Level is important in Dark Souls 2. If you're grossly overleveled compared to your friend, you won't be able to see their summon sign. The type of soap stone they use is important too. [Review and use this page](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator) to help calculate what you're doing, and to see what soul levels you can summon.

Comment: If I remember right, it's not just soul level, but also "soul memory" that impacts ability to connect. Soul memory is the total number of souls you have spent throughout the game, whether that be on levels, items, upgrades, spells, etc. This also includes souls that you lost and then failed to recover before dying again.

Comment: @MrSpudtastic Correct! Your soul level is determined by all of those factors. :)

Comment: Slight correction, matching is really done with soul memory, and soul memory is the sum of all souls you earned (except your own bloodstains), not souls spent.

Comment: Soul memory is actually sum of all souls that you came across.  If you lost souls from dying consecutively, the lost souls will count towards your soul memory, but your soul level won't go up (because you didn't spend any souls).